# Compare elements from one dataframe and put the output to another dataframe with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-requests, compare

I have two data frames like this:

df1:

```
     col1    col2          time
0    A        A_1          05:02:03
1    A        A_2          15:36:14
2    A        A_1          28:21:47
3    A        A_1          47:21:17
4    A        A_1          32:28:01
5    A        A_2          37:27:14
```

I want to compare if the time in column "time" is <24h, >24 but <48, >48 but <72h and >72 and put these results to another dataframe like this:

df2:

```
     col1    col2      time <24       24<time<48       48<time<72    time>72
0    A        A_1          1              3              NaN            NaN
1    A        A_2          1              1              NaN            NaN
```

So, basically what I want in this df2 is to have the count of files that meet comparison, like for example there are three files in "time" column that belong to A and A_1 and the time is 24<time<48, and we just put 3 in the "24<time<48" column.

I tried this code from @Andreas but it is failing if there is no time in "time" column that 48<time<72 and time>72:

```
df['day'] = (df['time'].str.split(':').str[0].astype(int)/24).astype(int)
df = df.pivot_table(index=['col1', 'col2'], columns=['day'], values=['time'], aggfunc='count').reset_index()

d = {'time0':'time <24', 'time1':'24<time<48', 'time2':'48<time<72', 'time3':'time>72'}
df.columns = [d.get(''.join(map(str, x)), ''.join(map(str, x))) for x in df.columns]
```

p.s Im making this as a new question because the other one got edited to many times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try:

1. Coverting Time Values to TimeDelta to get the days
2. `clip` to make sure values don't go beyond 3 days
3. Use a `pivot_table` then cleanup columns

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'A', 3: 'A', 4: 'A', 5: 'A'},
                   'col2': {0: 'A_1', 1: 'A_2', 2: 'A_1', 3: 'A_1', 4: 'A_1',
                            5: 'A_2'},
                   'time': {0: '05:02:03', 1: '15:36:14', 2: '28:21:47',
                            3: '47:21:17', 4: '32:28:01', 5: '37:27:14'}})

df['days'] = (
    pd.to_timedelta(df['time']).dt.days  # Get Days from Time Delta
        .clip(lower=0, upper=3)  # Clip at 3 Days
)

time_cols = ['time < 24', '24 <= time < 48',
             '48 <= time < 72', 'time >= 72']
df = (
    df.pivot_table(index=['col1', 'col2'],
                   columns='days',
                   aggfunc='count',
                   fill_value=np.nan)
        .droplevel(0, 1)  # Remove Column Multi Index
        .reset_index()  # Reset index
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1)  # Remove Axis Name
        .rename(columns={i: v for i, v in enumerate(time_cols)})
)

# Add Missing Columns
df[list(set(time_cols).difference(df.columns))] = np.nan

# Reorder Columns
df = df[['col1', 'col2', *time_cols]]
print(df)
```

`df`:

```
  col1 col2  time < 24  24 <= time < 48  48 <= time < 72  time >= 72
0    A  A_1          1                3              NaN         NaN
1    A  A_2          1                1              NaN         NaN
```

Comment: Thank you but something is strange, it is working in VS Code but it is not in Jupiter notebook. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: I just ran it in Jupyter notebook and it ran fine for me. Pandas 1.2.4 is the pandas version I'm using and Jupyter Notebook 6.3.0.